# scrollView.getScrollY() always returns 0 after a fragment change

Tags: android, scrollview, listener

I have to detect the scroll of a scrollview.

All works at the first launch.
But when I change fragment, and then return to the previous one, the listener is called but scrollView.getScrollY() return always 0.
The scrollview has many items and it's longer than the page.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged()           
        {               
            int new_scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();  
            if(new_scrollY == 0)        // First call when page is created  
                return;

            ....
        }
    }
```

The code above is placed in the onViewCreated method.

Thanks

Comment: This behavior may be caused by Fragments.. Have you made a prototype to produce this in activities only ? i.e make a sample project with 2 activities and implement this `ScrollView` .. If the issue doesn't persist.. then your culprit is Fragment.

Comment: I suppose that fragments are the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried the above using activities ? I've been working on Fragments for the past 1 year.. But first lets be 100% sure here if Fragments are indeed the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I have to remove each time that the fragment is changed the OnScrollChangedListener.
For example in the onPause().

Comment: So you are calling removeOnScrollListener(onScrollChangeListener); in onPause();  ??