# How to get current scrollbar position in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to get current position of scrollbar on screen. I supposed that getVerticalScrolbarPosition would do the trick, but for some reason it gives me only zeroes. Here is the code I use:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
(...)
getRecyclerView().setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int srollBarPosition = getRecyclerView().getVerticalScrollbarPosition();
        }
    });
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using getScrollY(), [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY%28%29) is the documentation :)

EDIT: hm, if for you can work anyway `getFirstVisiblePosition()` gives you not the y scrolls but the index of the first visible item of the list(might be the same, depending on what you need to do)

EDIT 2: i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153259/scrollview-getscrolly-always-returns-0-after-a-fragment-change) question, try reading it and probably you can solve the problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried that too, but it also gives me only 'zero' ):

Comment: @genoxide if for you can work anyway i wrote another way, a bit different but you can do 90% of things you could have done with heigth :S

Comment: Thank you! I'll try those options too.