# getScrollY() always returns 0 in OnScrollChangedListener

Tags: android, scrollview, android-gridlayout

I have a GridLayout as follows:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/chat_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_background"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/message_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:numColumns="1"
            />

    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView />

    <EditText/>

    <ImageView/>

</GridLayout>
```

I am trying to create an event when the `ScrollView` reaches the top by using the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview/23365539#23365539) inside fragment

```
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_scroll);
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
        Log.i(TAG, "scrollY: " + scrollY);
    }
});
```

However, the problem is I am always getting the value of scrollY as 0.

Comment: Try to remove each time that the fragment is changed the OnScrollChangedListener. For example in the onPause().
[source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153259/scrollview-getscrolly-always-returns-0-after-a-fragment-change)

Comment: @AbhayShukla Could you please tell the code to remove the listener? I am new to Android and Java. Also, I am just wondering why would `onPause` be called when I am in the same fragment?

Comment: I just noticed you dont have a delay after `final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_scroll);`

Your app might be taking time to initialize the view, so when you run `getScrollY()` your `ScrollView` isnt ready so it returns 0..

Try adding a delay and a splash screen after `final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_scroll);`

Comment: Did you find a solution?